# present.addPresent is not a function

Tags: mongodb, express, mern

I have been trying to access my method that I have declared in User Schema first but when I try to get access to my addPresent method in the controllers where I already have require User Schema and have created new User but again i am facing the same error again. I am fairly new to mongoose and express, and I'm pretty sure I have my files set up currently so I don't know what could be causing this issue. As a last attempt, I tried switching to arrow functions , but that didn't work either.

```
`Schema Section `
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  rollNo: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    // required: true,
  },
  department: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  section: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  confirmPassword: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  tokens: [
    {
      token: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  presents: [
    {
      date: {
        type: Date,
      },
      presentCount: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  ],
  leaves: [
    {
      date: {
        type: Date,
      },
      reason: {
        type: String,
      },
      leaveCount: {
        type: Number,
      },
    },
  ],
});
`Creating Methods`
userSchema.methods.addPresent = async function (count) {
  try {
    this.presents = this.presents.concat({
      date: Date.now(),
      presentCount: count,
    });
    await this.save();
    return this.presents;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

};
const user = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
module.exports = user;

`In controllers where i'm accessing my method`
const User = require("../models/userSchema");
exports.presentUser = async (req, res) => {
  const user = req.userRoot;
  const userId = req.userRoot._id;
  console.log(userId);
  count = count + 1;
  if (user) {
    const present = User.findOne({ _id: userId });
`Here is the main problem where i am accessing the addPresent method`
    if (present) {
      const addAttendance = await present.addPresent();
      await present.save();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: You need to await for your present object so please change const present = User.findOne({ _id: userId }); to const present = await User.findOne({ _id: userId });

Comment: Got it. Thank you now by using await i have stored all the User data from database in my present object so now I can concat my information by using addPresent function. Thanks.